# Something is wrong with my script in mysql and I cant figure it out

Tags: mysql, insert

I am inserting data into a new table I made called "PC" and there must be a problem with my code. Can anyone identify where I am making my mistake? This is my first table using just mysql btw. I am very new at this but I have a decent understanding of he material we have covered so far.  t

```
Insert into PC (PC_ID, Vendor, Model, Price, Notes) 
Values ('pc1', 'Dell', 'XPS 27 All-in-One', 2700,'Staff-pc'),
('pc2','Apple','Macbook Pro', 2800, 'Laptop-mac'),
('pc3','Apple','Macbook Pro', 2800,'Laptop-mac'),
('Pc4','Lenovo','IdeaCenter 730', 820, 'Staff-pc'), 
('Pc5','Lenovo','IdeaCenter 730', 820, 'Staff-pc'), 
('Pc6','Lenovo','IdeaCenter 730', 820, 'Staff-pc'), 
('Pc7','Lenovo','IdeaCenter 730', 820, 'Staff-pc'),
('Pc8','XPS 1370','XPS 1370', 1200, 'Laptop-pc'),
('Pc9','XPS 1370','XPS 1370', 1200, 'Laptop-pc'),
('Pc10','XPS 1370','XPS 1370', 1200, 'Laptop-pc')
```

Comment: Can you clarify what makes you think that "_Something is wrong_" and "_there must be a problem with my code_". What were you trying to do, what was the expected result, and what actual result did you get?

Comment: It wasn't running, sorry i wasn't specific enough for you. Thanks for the down vote though, now I can't ask any questions! Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I see is semicolon.

```
CREATE TABLE PC (PC_ID TEXT, Vendor TEXT, Model TEXT, Price  REAL, Notes TEXT);
Insert INTO PC (PC_ID, Vendor, Model, Price, Notes) 
VALUES 
('pc1', 'Dell', 'XPS 27 All-in-One', 2700,'Staff-pc'), 
('pc2','Apple','Macbook Pro', 2800, 'Laptop-mac'),
('pc3','Apple','Macbook Pro', 2800,'Laptop-mac'),
('Pc4','Lenovo','IdeaCenter 730', 820, 'Staff-pc'),
('Pc5','Lenovo','IdeaCenter 730', 820, 'Staff-pc'),
('Pc6','Lenovo','IdeaCenter 730', 820, 'Staff-pc'),
('Pc7','Lenovo','IdeaCenter 730', 820, 'Staff-pc'),
('Pc8','XPS 1370','XPS 1370', 1200, 'Laptop-pc'),
('Pc9','XPS 1370','XPS 1370', 1200, 'Laptop-pc'),
('Pc10','XPS 1370','XPS 1370', 1200, 'Laptop-pc');
SELECT * FROM PC;
```

works perfectly for me.